# Animation won't run until second loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, animation

Seems a pretty niche question, but here it goes.

I have an image scroller that needs to be a continuous loop. Everything runs just fine, except that the actual animation doesn't run until the second iteration.

```
<?php $images = scandir("Images/scroller"); ?>
var images = new Array();
images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
var i = 0;
function newImg(){
    if(i == images.length){
        i = 2;
    }

    var currentPicWidth = $("#wide").children().first().width() * -1;
    $("#wide").children().first().animate({'marginLeft': currentPicWidth}, 3200, "linear", function(){
        $("#wide").append("<img src='Images/scroller/" + images[i] + "' name='" + i + "' class='imgScroll'>\n").children().first().remove();
        i++;
        window.newImg();
    });
}
.
.
.
<div id="imageScroller">
    <div id="wide">
        <?php
            for($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++){
                echo "<img src='Images/scroller/" . $images[$i] . "' name='" . $i . "' class='imgScroll'>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
.
.
.

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(initPage(), newImg());
</script>
```

So since my animation is environmentally friendly and trashes / creates new elements as it needs, what happens is that for 3.2 seconds no animation runs then the first image is trashed and animation starts.

Any clever fixes?

Comment: give me a fiddle of outputed html, css and javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what's this `$(document).ready(initPage(), newImg());`? `.ready` only accepts one argument and its the name of the handler function (without parenthesis)

Comment: @koala_dev, I put a `window.newImg()` in the `initPage()` and it's still doing it. It might have been incorrect syntax, but Chrome didn't catch it, neither did jsfiddle and it worked just fine.

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/tPDNy/2/), fiddle was wrapping everything in a docuemnt ready function

Comment: @koala_dev, good catch. Works in fiddle, fails in application. Check the demo site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Syntax you provided is cut from the original script but this is not the problem 
The problem is $(document).ready() 
Ready executes after all elements are received,but not fully loaded (I mean rendered on screen).
So in ready you can't access css properties of element like width of images as you do 
And if u alerted the width of the first time it will be zero
The alternative is that

```
<body onload="newImg()"> ... </body> it will work
```

or The jquery Method

```
$(window).bind("load",newImg);
```

Note that there is shortcut for load in jquery

```
$(window).load(newImg); But it's deprecated in version 1.8
```